# how to find duplicated columns in row in R?

Tags: r

I have such a data frame below and I want to find duplicated columns in each row of this data frame. Please see the input and output example below. 0 is repeated 2 times in the first row, that is why column rep should be 0 (`data_input[1,"rep"]=0`); 2 is repeated 2 times in the second row, that is why column rep should be 0; there are no replicated values in the 3rd row that is why column rep can be 4 (or you can add any value instead of 0,1,2) and 1 is repeated 3 times in the 4th row, that is why column rep should be 1.

```
 data_input=data.frame(X1=c(0,1,2,1), X2=c(0,2,1,1), 
  X3=c(1,2,0,1)) 

 data_output=data.frame(X1=c(0,1,2,1), 
  X2=c(0,2,1,1), X3=c(1,2,0,1), rep=c(0,2,4,1))
```

Comment: So you essentially want to create the rep column so that it contains the most frequent value in that row and in case there are multiple such values just assign any kind of value, e.g. 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option with `rowwise` - create the rowwise attribute, then find the `duplicated` element from the row, if there are none, replace the `NA` with `4`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_input %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(rep = {tmp <- c_across(everything())
          replace_na(tmp[duplicated(tmp)][1], 4)
   }) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     X1    X2    X3   rep
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     1     0
2     1     2     2     2
3     2     1     0     4
4     1     1     1     1
```

Above solution didn't consider the case where there are multiple duplicates.  If there are, then either consider to create a `list` column or `paste` the `unique` elements together to a single string

```
data_input %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(rep = {tmp <- c_across(everything())
                tmp <- toString(sort(unique(tmp[duplicated(tmp)])))
                replace(tmp, tmp == "", "4")
   }) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     X1    X2    X3 rep  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     0     0     1 0    
2     1     2     2 2    
3     2     1     0 4    
4     1     1     1 1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data_input$rep <- apply(data_input, 1, FUN = \(x) x[anyDuplicated(x)][1])
data_input$rep[is.na(data_input$rep)] <- 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, based on base R:

```r
nCols <- ncol(data_input)

data_output <- cbind(
 data_input, rep = apply(data_input, 1,
  function(x) if (length(table(x)) != nCols) x[which.max(table(x))] else nCols+1))

data_output

#>   X1 X2 X3 rep
#> 1  0  0  1   0
#> 2  1  2  2   2
#> 3  2  1  0   4
#> 4  1  1  1   1
```